# Looking for the intersect of two sets if posible

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have this problem here and I am looking for solutions using two partial solutions.

The periodic autocorrelation function associated to a finite sequence
$A = [a_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}]$ of length $n$ is defined as
$$
P_A(s) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k  a_{k+s}, \,\, s = 0, \ldots, n-1,
$$
where $k+s$ is taken modulo $n$, when $k+s \geq n$.

$P_A(s) + P_B(s) = 2, \forall \,\, s = 1,\ldots,\displaystyle\frac{n-1}{2}$

Lets say the solutions are given by a python program as,

```
A =  [-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1] 
B =  [1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
#PAF(A)+PAF(B) for values of S -> [2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  -2  2  2  -2  2  2  10  ] 
A =  [1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1] 
B =  [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1]
#PAF -> [2  -2  2  2  2  6  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  ]
```

My question is see how these answers are close and the constraints overlap, Is there some technique to find an intersect of these two solutions to reduce the search space of a correct solution? Like if I use my exhaustive search algorithm is there a known way anyone has seen to use these two almost solutions to make it much easier to find a full solution?